# Converting a number to string with multiple arguments

Tags: c, type-conversion, atoi

I want to convert a number **x** of a base **n** to a string and store it in **str**. **str** has the max size of **max**. In this program I don't want to use any library functions. If I reach the maximum size of the array, the function should return false and the array contents should be undefined.

The prototype of the function looks like this:

```
bool num2str(int x, char *str, unsigned n, unsigned max);
```

How would I go about making this work? I'm having trouble understanding the algorithm behind it.

I also need to check the value of **n**, but I already did that:

```
bool num2str(int x, char *str, unsigned n, unsigned max)
{
    assert(n >= 2 && n <= 36);
    return true;
}
```

But that's all I could do. Please help.

Comment: What do you do in the class?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about completing one's homework.

Comment: Sounds like homework. Try explaining what in the algorithm is not clear.

Comment: It's one of the test questions. I want to understand it more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a number in base 10: 123456. Now let's repeatedly apply a modulus and an integer division using the number and base 10:

```
123456 mod 10 = 6
123456 div 10 = 12345

12345 mod 10 = 5
12345 div 10 = 1234
```

As you can see, modulus by base extracts the last digit, while integer division by base shifts the number on digit to the right. You can do the same for any base. Hope this hint is enough.

Comment: @user3647430 it will be *very* handy to use the modulo in each step as an index into a static char buffer that looks like "0123456789ABCDE....XYZ" for calculating your output chars, btw, though you're going to find one final change has to be done to the resulting string to get all the calculated digits in proper order.

Comment: @WhozCraig well, is it going to have to be reversed? since the modulo takes it from the last digit?

Comment: @user3647430 I would say that is a distinct possibility =P if you're storing them starting at `str[0]`, then `str[1]`, etc...

Comment: Recursing passing x div n iff (x div n > 0), before you convert the digit to char let's you build the string up forwards, as the stack unwinds.